# MetadataGenerator of Spring Security SAML doesn't support redirect binding for Assertion consumer service

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

HTTP_Redirect binding is not supported for Assertion Consumer Service in MetadataGenerator.

When you check for source code of org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.**MetadataGenerator.java** you find following comment in **buildSPSSODescriptor** method.

***// Assertion consumer MUST NOT be used with HTTP Redirect, Profiles 424, same applies to HoK profile***

Can anyone let me know, why is it, as we had an IdP asking for ACS URL with redirect binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the comment, SAML 2.0 standard explicitly prohibits usage of HTTP-Redirect for delivery of SAML assertions. Spring SAML follows this.

The Profile 424 refers to this document http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf

Your IDP may not be fully aware of the standard's requirements.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I missed the point that it would not be possible to have complete SAML response in query Parameter as URL length will exceed. Will check with the IdP, and ask them to enforce this.